# Not able to access data from Django in angularjs

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to access the django data from angularjs using service and controller but I seem to be having some trouble
This is what I have got so far

```
var Events = angular.module("Events",["ngCookies"],function($interpolateProvider){
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol("((");
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol("))");
});

Events.run(function ($http, $cookies) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies['csrftoken'];
});

Events.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl:"static/js/myapp/views/main.html",
        controller:"MainController",
        resolve:{
            events:function (EventService) {
                return EventService.list();
            }
        }
    })
});

Events.controller('MainController', function ($scope, events) {
    $scope.events = events.data;
}

Events.factory('EventService', function ($http, $q) {
var api_url = "/events/";
return {
    get: function (event_id) {
        var url = api_url + event_id + "/";
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
            success(function (data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                defer.reject(status);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    },
    list: function () {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'GET', url: api_url}).
            success(function (data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                defer.reject(status);
            });
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
});
```

Please help.....I am new at this.
Any help will be appreciated :

**Edit**

**model**

```
class event(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And I have inserted the data via admin so yes it is responding to the app,

**main.html**

```
<table border="1px black" >
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
<div ng-repeat="event in events">
    <tr >
        <td>
            <a href="((event.event_url))">
                ((event.title))
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            ((event.description))
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
</table>
```

This is the View I am calling using $routeProvider

Comment: So what is the problem exactly..?

Comment: The data is not Displaying in The Angular view

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information here. Is Angular actually making the query to /events/? Is your Django app responding with data? What does that data look like (try logging it to the browser developer console)?

Comment: I have updated the question with additional information